# In java doc comments is @see used with {@link } or without?

Tags: java, javadoc

When I want to put comment to see the other method which one is correct? With `{@link ClassName#methodName}` or without?

```
/**
 * @see ClassName#methodName
 *
 * @see {@link ClassName#methodName}
 */
```

Comment: The second one is more convenient, the other isn't. This isn't a question about "correct" or "incorrect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `@see`, the clickable link is already included, making `@link` redundant. Everywhere else if you want to make a clickable link then use `@link`. If not, don't. Simple as that.

```
/**
 * Blah blah {@link SomeClass#foo}.
 * 
 * @see SomeClass#bar
 * @see {@link SomeClass#baz}
 */
```

The bottom two will be generated the same. `SomeClass#foo` will also be a clickable link.